Is It Halal To Work Under Someone Else’s Name And Credentials In A Remote IT Job
Assalam o Alaikum.
Hi everyone. I hope you are doing good. I am reaching out to seek guidance regarding a situation that involves working for a remote IT company under unusual circumstances.
A friend of mine has recently secured a position in a remote IT company. Although he possesses considerable experience in the IT industry (about 5 years more than me), he is not well-versed in the specific domain required for this new job. Despite this, he was hired based on his general experience and credentials.
However, since he is not an expert in the required domain, he has proposed that I perform the actual job tasks while using his name and credentials. This involves taking calls and sharing camera as well.
I am confident that I have the necessary skills to execute the job requirements excellently and provide outstanding results. Unfortunately, due to my comparatively lower level of experience, I would not be eligible to apply or get shortlisted for this position on my own merits at this stage.
Now I am concerned whether is it permissible (halal) for me to work under someone else’s identity, despite being capable of fulfilling the job requirements?
Your insights and advice on whether pursuing this arrangement would be halal or not would be greatly appreciated.
JazakAllah for your time and guidance.
